# Widget widths: 50% + 50% > 100%?

Tags: gwt, google-apps-script

I am using *Google Apps Script* and the *Apps Script UI Builder*, which is based on *GWT* widgets.

If I create a *Flow Panel*, and add two *Labels* of 50% width, then these labels appear on separate lines. But isn't 50% + 50% = 100%.

> How do I make them appear on the same line?

To try it out yourself:

1. Open a Google Spreadsheet.
2. In the Spreadsheet menu, click: *Tools / Script Editor...*
3. In the Script Editor menu, click: *File / Build a user interface...*
4. Add the widgets to the canvas.

Of course this question doesn't just apply to the problem with the labels. In general I am totally puzzled concerning how to build flowing layouts with the *UI Builder*. There seem to be (hidden?) paddings and margins that make things very hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple. For both labels, set to *zero*:

*Borders and Margins / Margin*

Don't know why I didn't see that yesterday - I was doing a night shift... ;-)

Comment: This is Tassos Bassoukos' answer.

Comment: I disagree: I was asking how to do things in the *GUI Builder*. Furthermore, using *CSS Reset*, as suggested by Tassos doesn't make sense. The Google Apps GUI (Builder) widgets abstract HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 2):

It's all based on CSS and its box model, and that issue has accumulates cruft over the last 15 years or so. In essence, the widths you specify don't take into account margings (and/or possibly padding, it's been a while), so you will need to add a stylesheed that minimizes them. See something like this [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Comment: I know CSS quite well, but in this case I thought that I don't need to bother with it. Note that the widgets are not *native* HTML widgets. They are *GWT* widgets, converted to somewhat ugly HTML (lots of tables, etc.).

Comment: GWT sits on top of HTML and emits HTML, which *is* affected by CSS rules. There's no issue of it being native/non-native, it'all HTML. Sorry, leaky abstraction and all that.

Comment: GWT abstracts HTML. Loading *CSS reset* doesn't feel right, if even if it was possible with *Apps Script*. There is special functionality for setting *white listed* CSS properties.

Answer (score 0):

`Label`s translate to `<div>`s, which appear on different lines by default.  You could try adding `float: left` to the labels, or change the display mode, etc.

You could also try `InlineLabel`s, which I think compile to `<span>`s.

If you've already tried all this, then your `Label`s are apparently just too wide.  It's annoying that two 50% objects wouldn't fit on the same line, but what isn't annoying about working with HTML and CSS?

Comment: Labels in the UI builder do *not* appear on different lines by default when used in a *Flow Panel*. The corresponding CSS (`float`) is applied automatically. Try it out, and have a look using e.g. Chrome developer tools.

Comment: It must depend on what theme you have loaded.  I disabled all built-in GWT styles.  I wonder what Google Apps uses - probably the default.

Comment: As far as I know, there are is no concept of *themes* for UIs built with the *Apps Script GUI Builder*. The HTML of a *default* label (no custom settings), created with the *Apps Script GUI Builder*: `<div class="gwt-Label" style="display: block; width: 120px; z-index: 9; overflow: hidden; margin: 3px; height: 25px; background-color: white; float: left; position: relative; ">Label</div>`